# Prove that if $P^{-1}AP=diag[\lambda_j]$ then $e^{At}=Pdiag[e^{\lambda_j t}]P^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, linear-transformations

I'm stuck in this exercise.

> If $P^{-1}AP=diag[\lambda_j]$ then $e^{At}=Pdiag[e^{\lambda_j t}]P^{-1}$

This is what I've done:

$$P^{-1}AP=diag[\lambda_j]$$

$$\implies AP=Pdiag[\lambda_j]$$

$$\implies A=Pdiag[\lambda_j]P^{-1}$$

$$\implies At=Pdiag[\lambda_jt]P^{-1}$$

$$\implies e^{At}=e^{Pdiag[\lambda_jt]P^{-1}}$$

And I need the last implication to be equal to $e^{At}=Pdiag[e^{\lambda_j t}P^{-1}]$

If anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: Use the definition of $e^{At}$.

Comment: @Chappers in the last implication? or in the beginning of the proof $e^{At}=Pdiag[e^{\lambda_j t}]P^{-1}$?

Answer (score 2):

Notice (or check) that $(PDP^{-1})^n = PD^nP^{-1}$ for all $n \ge 0$. Since $e^{PDP^{-1}}$ is built up of such terms, we can take a limit (with respect to the appropriate matrix norm) to obtain
$$e^{PDP^{-1}} = P e^{D} P^{-1}.$$
Now $D = \text{diag}(\lambda_j t)$, so it remains to prove $e^D = \text{diag}(e^{\lambda_jt})$. Much as above for conjugation, this will follow by observing that for all $n \ge 0$,
$$\text{diag}(\lambda_jt)^n = \text{diag}((\lambda_j t)^n).$$

Comment: $e^{PDP^{-1}}$ is built up of such terms?  how do you know that?

Comment: @Isabella What’s your definition of the exponential of a matrix?

Comment: @amd do you mean a linear operator? if yes, it is $e^T=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} T^k/k!$

Comment: @Isabella Well, there you go. Each term in that sum involves a power of $T$, i.e., of the matrix $PDP^{-1}$.

Comment: @amd another argument for this $e^D = \text{diag}(e^{\lambda_jt})$ can be that $e$ can be treated like a real constant $c$ $(cD=c\lambda_i)$?